# simple c++ file opening issue

Tags: c++, file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  ofstream testfile;
  testfile.open ("test.txt");
  testfile << "success!\n";
  testfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

1)called "g++ testfile.cpp"
2)created "test.txt"
3)called "chmod u+x a.out"
4)???
5)file remains blank.

I feel like an idiot for failing at something as trivial as this is supposed to be.

Comment: But did you actually run a.out? And there is no need to create test.txt

Comment: Your code works as is in VS2005.

Comment: are you running the executable from the same directory where it resides?

Answer (score 5):

When performing file I/O, you almost always need to test for errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  ofstream testfile;
  testfile.open ("test.txt");
  if ( ! testfile.is_open() ) {
     cerr << "file open failed\n";
     return 1;
  }

  if ( ! testfile << "success!\n" ) {
     cerr << "write failed\b";
     return 1;
  }

  testfile.close();   // failure unlikely!
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) use "(!( testfile << "success!\n" ))" not (! testfile << "success!\n" )

still does nothing.

I also tried adding "cout<<"something";" at the start of the main function.

I am beginning to believe the problem is not in the executable syntax

Comment: @Robert Good catch. I think your problem is to do with your environment, or your understanding of it, and not with your understanding of C++.

Comment: you don't have to close the file. it's on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

In theory they're equivalent, but just to make sure, do try `<< endl` instead of `"\n"` to flush the stream.

```
ofstream testfile;
testfile.open ("test.txt");
testfile << "success!" << endl;
testfile.close();
```